# Where to keep the zipped file of kafka connect s3-source connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I have downloaded the s3-source connector zip file as given in the confluent web page. I am not getting where to place the extracted files. I am getting the following error

[image: error image]

Please guide me. To load the connector, Iam using this command -

```
confluent local load s3-source -- -d /etc/kafka-connect-s3/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3-source-1.3.2/etc/quickstart-s3-source.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am not getting where to place the extracted files

If you used `confluent-hub install`, it would put them in the correct place for you.

Otherwise , you can put them whereever, if you update `plugin.path` in the Connect properties to include the parent directory of the JARs for the connector

Answer (score 0):

Extract the zip file whether its a source connector or sink connector and place the whole folder with all the jars inside of  it under: plugin.path which you have set